# How do I display an encrypted message from a text file using ASCII in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii

I am trying to display an encrypted message by converting the characters in a string within a text file into their equivalent ASCII values. Once this is done, I would like to add an offset factor, say 10 and then convert back and display the message. Furthermore, I would also like it if somebody could overlook the spaces, meaning they do not get encrypted.Finally, a bonus would be if somebody could deduct 94 from the ASCII value if it's higher than 126.

So far, I've "generated" the integers, but all I all I get is square brackets

```
user_input = input("Enter a text file name. Remeber to add 'txt'")
file = open(user_input,"r+") 
print(file.readline())

int_text = ([ord(c) for c in file.readline()])
print(int_text)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does it actually open the file? you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: This looks like Python 3, so no, they shouldn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Answer (score 1):

`shifting` is taking a text and an optional offset factor and returns the transformed string:

```
def shifting(text, n=10):
    ints = (ord(c) for c in text)
    def helper():
        for c in ints:
            if c==32:
                yield " "
            elif c+n > 126:
                yield chr(c+n-94)
            else:
                yield chr(c+n)
    return "".join(helper())

enc_text = shifting(file.readline(),10)
```